# OneDrive code flow asking to log in to Microsoft account

Tags: php, oauth, onedrive

Whenever I try to authenticate the OneDrive API it asks me to log in to my Microsoft account, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of the API?

I redirect my script to the Auth Code URL which should return a unique code for me to request an access token. It works fine when I am logged in to my Microsoft account but when I am not logged in it shows me to the Microsoft login page.

The URL I am using is

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=MYCLIENTID&scope=onedrive.readwrite offline_access onedrive.readonly onedrive.appfolder&response_type=code&redirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURL
```

**EDIT**

Here is the PHP code I am using to redirect

```
$auth_code_url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id='.$od_app_id.'&scope=onedrive.readwrite offline_access onedrive.readonly onedrive.appfolder&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$url_website;

header("Location: ".$auth_code_url); exit();
```

Comment: its not the url. You need to post the code you are using to do the authentication so we can take a look

Comment: Just added a code example, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The API allows you to manage a user's files on their behalf, it does not create a OneDrive account for your application/service.

In order to manage a user's files, they need to authorize you to do so. Conceptually this means the user talks to login.live.com and says "I'm UserX, here's my proof". login.live.com then gives them back a token saying "We believe that this user is UserX". The user then provides this token to your service, so that when you make OneDrive requests you can provide the token to say "UserX gave me permission to manage their files".

If the user is already logged in, their browser already has an auth cookie stored so login.live.com will give back a code/token without prompting for login. If the user is not logged in, login.live.com (and also your service) has no idea who the user is. So it is necessary to show the login screen to get/verify the user's identity so that you know whose files to modify.